# Azure ARM Unexpected character encountered while parsing value [

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I've changed my ARM parameters ("**Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks**") to include multiple prefixes , but now I am getting the **InvalidJson** error with message "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: *[. Path 'properties.addressSpace.addressPrefixes', line 1, position 71."*

```
..."parameters": {        
        "addressPrefix": {
            "value": [ 
                "10.18.0.0/17",
                "10.90.0.0/19"
            ]
          },...
```

the corresponding part of template is shown below

```
..."properties": {
          "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
              "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
            ]
          },...
```

Not sure why it happens because I have similar construct for "**Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways**"

Comment: I can see now that addressPrefixes is required to be string, not  sure how to make array string thou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the template so that the array in the parameter value is assigned directly to the `addressPrefixes` property instead of the array of the property.

```
..."properties": {
          "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
          },...
```